# Error when declaring dynamic slots in Vue template

Tags: typescript, vue.js

When I try to compile this through vue-tsc:

```
<template v-for="(_, slotName) in slots" #[slotName]="slotProps">
  <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="slotProps"></slot>
</template>
```

I get the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type 'Readonly<{ default?: ((arg: { isActive: Ref<boolean>; }) => VNode<RendererNode, RendererElement, { [key: string]: any; }>[]) | undefined; activator?: ((arg: { ...; }) => VNode<...>[]) | undefined; }>'.

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Readonly<{ default?: ((arg: { isActive: Ref<boolean>; }) => VNode<RendererNode, RendererElement, { [key: string]: any; }>[]) | undefined; activator?: ((arg: { ...; }) => VNode<...>[]) | undefined; }>'.

3     <template v-for="(_, slotName) in slots" #[slotName]="slotProps">
```

I have tried:

- to type component through vue-shim
- type $slots
- coercing slotName type to `any`
- declaring defineSlots macros with `any` as a generic